# Why total keeps equalling 0 ? Help me please

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python, right here I'm trying to get the value of x, y and z from input and calculate the total. But total keeps equalling 0?

Please help me, thank you so much

```
   total = 0 
   x = 0
   y = 0
   z = 0
   prices = [x, y, z]
   i = 0 
   while i < 3:
       purchase = int(input('purchase?'))
       i += 1
       if x == 0:
       x += purchase
       else:
           if y == 0:
               y += purchase
           elif z == 0:
               z += purchase
   for price in prices:
       total += price
   print(f'your total is {total}').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the purchases to the variables x, y and z but never update the array so when you add up the total, you're adding an array filled with nothing.

You could do this, using the array and its index:

```
total = 0 
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
prices = [x, y, z]
i = 0 
while i < 3:
   purchase = int(input('purchase?'))
   i += 1
   if x == 0:
       prices[0] += purchase
   else:
       if y == 0:
           prices[1] += purchase
       elif z == 0:
           prices[2] += purchase
for price in prices:
   total += price
print(f'your total is {total}')
```

Or this, constructing the array at the end:

```
total = 0 
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
i = 0 
while i < 3:
   purchase = int(input('purchase?'))
   i += 1
   if x == 0:
       x += purchase
   else:
       if y == 0:
           y += purchase
       elif z == 0:
           z += purchase
prices = [x, y, z]
for price in prices:
   total += price

print(f'your total is {total}')
```